# How to use firebase api in service and pass values to directives

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularjs-directive, angular-services

I'm new to angular and have an app which pulls data from a firebase instance. How can I put the firebase connection in an Angular service, and pass the returned data to the `users` directive? The firebase data is currently just being rendered to the `users-directive` in the markup, but its not being done through the directive itself. How can I pass it correctly to the directive to have it display only the names?

**Controller**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['firebase']);

myApp.controller('ChatCtrl', ['$scope', '$firebaseArray', function($scope, $firebaseArray){
  var myUsers = new Firebase('https://db.firebaseio.com/users');
  console.log(myUsers)
  $scope.users = $firebaseArray(myUsers);
  $scope.showUsers = function(users){
    $scope.users = users.name;
    $scope.users = users.userId;
  }
}]);

chatApp.directive("showUsers", function(){
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      user: '@'
    },
    templateUrl: "usersList.tpl.html"
  };
});
```

**userslist template**

```
<p>Users</p>
<ol class="list-unstyled animated fadeInDown" ng-repeat="user in users">
  <li><a href="#" id="{{user.userId}}">{{user.name}}</a></li>
</ol>
```

**JSBIN**: [LINK](https://jsbin.com/dozenipuro/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: it's not really clear what you are asking here.  You are showing code for a directive, but not showing where you are actually using the directive.

Comment: Ah, it was missing from the question, but in the jsbin: `<users-directive users="users">{{users}}</users-directive>`. I should be able to drop that line wherever on my page and have the users show up, but I'm not sure how to correctly use the directive and have it pull the names in.

Comment: what is `<users-directive>`?  that isn't defined here;  you don't include `directive` in your element name unless it is actually part of the name;  also, you shouldn't use a `-` in the name, unless you are using uppercase in the directive name. (the `-` is used for [normalization in directives](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#!))

Comment: I'm currently able to output the users with this: `<ul ng-repeat="user in users"><li>{{user.name}}</li></ul>`, but how can I move this to a template that is called by the users directive?

Comment: are you wanting a directive that takes the list of users and prints the list, or are you wanting a directive that takes a single user and prints that user details?

Comment: I'd like a directive that takes the list of users and prints the list. Each user in the list should have an associated id (which is already in the users list), so that clicking on the user allows the application to pull associated data for that user.

Comment: right, and that's what that template seems to do, but your `users` directive doesn't accept a `users` array in `scope`, it accepts `list` and `title`, and doesn't appear to use either of them.

Comment: I've updated the directive, but not sure how to use it to pass the users to the template. And then how to use the template to show the users.

Comment: I threw together a quick [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/6mwYYndVMKP90otcpHbh?p=preview) (I use plunker instead of jsbin because you can include multiple files).  it shows, briefly, how to pass a list from the parent into the directive.  Also, I changed your HTML of the template;  the `ng-repeat` should be on the item you want repeated (the `li`, not the `ol`).